# Vacuum Polarization and Effective Coupling (Peskin and Schroeder Page 255)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

In Peskin and Schroeder (PS) charge renormalized effective coupling up to leading order is given as,

$$\alpha_{\text{eff}}(q^2)=\frac{\alpha}{1-\hat{\Pi}_2(q^2)}\tag{1}$$

Where,

$$\hat{\Pi}_2(q^2)=-\frac{2\alpha}{\pi}\int_0^1dx\,x(1-x)\log\left(\frac{m^2}{m^2-x(1-x)q^2}\right)\tag{2}$$

For an on shell momentum $q^2$ in s channel, PS derived the Uehling potential by considering large distance approximation, arriving at,

$$V(r)=-\frac{\alpha}{r}\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{4\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{e^{-2mr}}{(mr)^{3/2}}+\cdots\right)\tag{3}$$

PS then mentions that the correction to the potential is due to screening by $e^+e^-$ pairs causing the vacuum to behave as a dielectric **where the apparent charge is less that the true charge**. I would like to know how from this potential can one make such a claim? As far as I can see in all regions of $r\gg 1/m$ the term in the bracket is more than one. Shouldn't it be then that the correction term is causing an increase in the effective charge? I know this goes completely against any physical intuition of charge screening, but I can't seem to get the same intuition from the equation.

Additionally PS go on to describe a small distance scenario in which they took the approximation $-q^2\gg m^2$. I don't understand how an off shell high energy scenario is related to smaller distance mathematically. It is something to do with the high energy probe distance? What is the explicit relation between $-q^2$ and $r$ then? Additionally up until now I was working with the assumption that on shell momentum causes a branch cut which gave rise to the correction term in the potential $(3)$. Why are we suddenly taking an off shell condition here?

The effective coupling under this approximation can be derived from $(2)$ where we get,

$$\alpha_{\text{eff}}(q^2)=\frac{\alpha}{1-\frac{\alpha}{3\pi}\log\left(\frac{-q^2}{Am^2}\right)}\tag{4}$$

where $A=\exp{5/3}$. PS mentioned that this coupling increases as we approach smaller distances. However if I take a naïve $-q^2\to\infty$ limit, this effective coupling goes to zero. Of course there will be a pole at $\frac{\alpha}{3\pi}\log\left(\frac{-q^2}{Am^2}\right)=1$, but such a pole does not correspond to $r=0$, assuming some naïve $r\propto 1/q$. How should I interpret this equation?

I'm self studying Quantum Field Theory from PS and don't really have anywhere to seek clarification. I'll really appreciate some help.

Comment: As you start to raise $-q^2$ above $m^2$, the effective coupling increases. That's the important statement. Of course this increase will turn into a decrease after you pass the pole. But they don't add this caveat because perturbative results become unreliable long before that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. Can you tell me the how is $-q^2$ related to $r$ and why should we consider a off shell 4 momentum in the small distance case, while an on shell 4 momentum in the large distance approximation of the Uehling potential?

Comment: I think they use the term "short distance" instead of "high energy" in the natural unit system.  Naively, it relates $q^2 \sim 1/r$, but exact relation maybe relate the typical scale of wavelength and energy, which has no rigorous math. That corresponds to scale of probes in HEP experiments, as you mentioned.